# Fanatic badge lost for 99 days

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I just lost the opportunity to get the fanatic badge because I was traveling yesterday for more than 15 hours and I didn't have any way to connect to SO.
I had 99 successive days :( and now I have to restart from zero, is there any tolerance for such thing :) ?

Comment: Well from today it's only 99 days until you get your badge so you already have a day again for today! (And [We don't need no stinking badges](https://youtu.be/XT8hE7_8BCY?t=18s))

Comment: It's *fanatic*, not *somewhat interested*. Show your true dedication in the next 99 days!

Comment: Ask yourself: what true fanatic would be away from the object of his fanaticism for an entire day?

Comment: Actually it is for 101 days and the tolerance starts at 100 and goes up to 102. I'm really sorry you missed it for 2 +/- 1 days.

Comment: LOL - upvoted to counter all of the downvotes that people only did to get the downvote badge. This post is the story of my life. One day...one day I'll set my circadian rhythm to UTC and get this badge. Then I'll finally have respect.

Comment: @KyleVassella haha you made my day :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no tolerance - you have to have logged in and done something for 100 consecutive UTC days.

I wouldn't "work" for this one, if it happens it happens but it doesn't actually help *you* at all. If you want a badge work for one of the ones that help you or the community.