# Tolerance in Enthusiast and Fanatic badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

I'm posting to suggest (re)considering tolerance in the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.  I've noted some sporadic discussion on the issue historically and seemingly a general pessimism on the topic, such as here: [Fanatic badge lost for 99 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291506/fanatic-badge-lost-for-99-days)
 which generated some considerable down votes.  Although, this pessimism seems  to reflect on request to recoup a lost day for various reasons (a fate I suffered as well and inspired the post, but not the intention for the post).

I write to suggest revising the formula/tolerance for the badges by discussing the purpose of these badges?  In my view, they are among the few badge types that permit a motivated individual to earn a recognition entirely by their own diligence.  That is, by "showing up" and visiting the site.  Rather than being validated by an upvote, approved edit, accepted answer, etc.  Granted, merely showing up is a pretty low bar. Yet, the badge provides an incentive to show up and, hopefully, once here, the visitor makes a contribution to the community.  It's a good trade that may give just the little extra kick to motivate an incremental day's visit. Strictly enforcing consecutive daily visit with no wiggle room does make it challenging when other life issues arise. Especially for the busy professionals the site would seemingly aim to attract.

Finding points reset after a long plane ride, an impossible day or minor calamity might conversely serve as a disincentive.  Again, if the purpose of the badge is to provide that little extra push to help drive traffic and community participation, a little tolerance in the threshold could help the busy individual stay motivated.  It seems good for the individual who's seeking that incentive and good for the site to gain some additional participation.

I suggest something like 30 out of 35 days and 100 out of 110 consecutive days would better serve to incentivize individuals who are motivated by the badge, help keep-up community participation that is pushed by the badges; and avoid the possibility of discouraging participating should unforseen circumstances prevent an individual's truly consecutive daily visit in the time window required.

Note regarding possible duplication flag of [Why I believe the Fanatic badge should be canceled/reformulated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291316/why-i-believe-the-fanatic-badge-should-be-canceled-reformulated): I did read that before hand and its a remarkable different discussion about suggesting people should "go on vacation, do sports, fish, spend time with his/her loved ones etc." And asks: "Is it really commendable that he/she is sneaking over to their laptops to check out SO."  Whether or not people should be incentivized to go out and play vs to log in to SO is a very different discussion.  And certainly different from this discussion that asks if badges can be better tuned to prompt further participation through the specific types of incentives created by these types of badges in particular.

Comment: It's supposed to be hard. It's a GOLD badge. All shiny and yellowish.

Comment: @yivi: That argument might stand up if you couldn't easily get a gold badge by asking a question that gets seen a lot.

Comment: So.... Once you make it 100 out of 110, when someone posts the exact same argument you put, but then say 'I was at 99 out of 108, then I had an emergency and couldn't log for a week's. Will we change to 100 out of 120? Then 130. Then 'just log 100 times, you'll get it. We don't care about consecutive'. At that point... Just drop the badge IMHO.

Comment: The comment above is ridiculous but gets upvotes. If you have a clear rule, then it is just a clear rule, as it is now as well. You can make 100 out of 120, or 2 days per week free of SO. No issue, simply nothing to criticise about. Any comment about GOLD badge as well: whatever the badge, if it is just not OK as a badge, whether is not OK, if it is hard to catch or not.

Answer (score 14):

> I suggest something like 30 out of 35 days and 100 out of 110 consecutive days would better serve to incentivize individuals who are motivated by the badge, help keep-up community participation that is pushed by the badges; and avoid the possibility of discouraging participating should unforseen circumstances prevent an individual's truly consecutive daily visit in the time window required.

The gold version of badge is literally called fanatic.  Not just fan, but fanatic.  As in "a person filled with excessive and single-minded zeal" to make sure to visit every single day, rain or shine, in sickness and in health to get this badge.  I won't pretend to know the motivations for these badges' existence, or even if the behaviors it encourages are productive.  But I think that this badge would lose a lot of its meaning if the consecutive days aspect was eliminated, as your feature request suggests.

Comment: Hi - 2658 consecutive days out of 2664 - "productive" is a strong word, given that if I didn't check *this* site every day, I'd probably be checking social media more than I do.  So in a way, maybe it is since I don't [have to see people die on every molehill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380463/1079354)?

Comment: This would be an actual interested metric to add to the Moderator Candidate Score.  Still not as important as actual activity, but I think such dedication to at least visiting the site speaks well for capacity for moderation.

Comment: Someone has written a bot in the past to accomplish Fanatic on all of the network sites, so no, I'm not convinced that this is a useful metric...

Comment: I agree with your comment.  Massive zeal.  But the thrust of my comment is on incentives and the purpose of badges.  Surely someone that you describe isn't showing up to earn a badge....if they get it, great!  But what's the purpose of badges and points for that matter except to incentivize participation.

Comment: In terms of bots... Okay, sure there are cheaters -- but it also evidences that the badge provides someone enough incentive to write a bot to do it.  In other words, it works.  It seems I've garnered tremendous down votes by suggesting a way to make incentives work even better to encourage additional participation on the site.  I think that's a pity.

Comment: You’ve garnered tremendous downvotes because people disagree with your feature request, @Soren. As do I. Watering down what “fanatic” means because it’s hard to achieve kinda misses the point. A true fanatic is not going to let a long plane ride interrupt their dedication to the site. They’ll pay for in-flight Wi-Fi. Or they’ll log on from the terminal at least *once* in a 24-hour period. In keeping with the general spirit of your feature request, but not modifying the existing fanatic badge, see [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265240/weekday-warrior-badge).

Comment: fanatic should ring everyone's alarm bells. This is a bad incentive with ignorance for social life, and it adds to the nerd image and it adds some cold atmosphere as if SO was day trading in stocks. I have accidentally upvoted your question, I am completely astonished about the intolerance of the community towards these freezingly cold badges.

Comment: If your religion prohibits getting a badge or you feel that it promotes an unhealthy lifestyle, just skip the badge. They're just silly incentives to be involved in the site by achieving made-up goals. Getting one or not has no real consequence whatsoever. BTW, if you think Fanatic is a hard badge to get, take a look at Epic or Legendary. If Fanatic is cold, Legendary is a nuclear winter.

Answer (score 8):

One part of showing up means that you know what time you're arriving.  Many people who lose out on the Fanatic-class of badges aren't as aware of what time UTC translates to in their local time zone, and by consequence, they aren't able to plan when they can access the site and have their participation actually *count*.

Since almost any "activity" on the site counts - even actions taken with the mobile app if you still happen to have that installed - it's harder to justify tweaking the period since, well, all you really have to do is show up.

Comment: **"all you really have to do is show up"** - This is exactly the proof of no empathy. Showing up on SO on your friend's wedding? Leaving some days special for religious, traditional or curtural reasons should meet anyone's understanding in my eyes, but exactly the opposite seems to be the case. **Just showing up is already too much on a special day.**

Comment: @Lorenz:  If you have thirty seconds to check your phone, you have thirty seconds to log into Stack Overflow.  Not seeing an issue.

Comment: Disagree, and not just for the sake of disagreeing, but for a true view on it: you must have a day off, it is not about 1 second or 30 seconds, it is for the sake of being free from everyday life at some special days. This is important for some people. Just imagine an Israeli Pilot logging in on SO on sabbath while his plane stands still the whole day. Think of people who cherish a day by keeping it special. This is just a respectful and relaxed approach to human culture, and it is not about making the badge easier or put down the many enthusiastic users here. I see this issue clearly.